# JSON .NET - annot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I read a lot of topics about this problem but couldn't find a solution. I have JSON returned by AP

```
{
    "Version": "XXX",
    "StatusCode": 400,
    "RequestId": "XXX",
    "Success": false,
    "ValidationMessages": {
        "SomeTable[0].PropName": [
       "This field is invalid"
        ],
        "SomeTable[1].PropName": [
            "This field is invalid"
        ],
        "SomeTable[0].OtherProp": [
            "This field is invalid"
        ]
    },
    "Result": {}
}
```

I created class:

```
public class MyResponse
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public SomeResult Result { get; set; }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> ValidationMessages { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to deserialize JSON, I am getting an error from the title. How can I achieve serialization of dynamic ValidationMessages?

Comment: ValidationMessages in the json is not a collection, its an object and you are trying to deserialize it into a collection. That's why you are getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific scenario you can use a Dictionary instead a List since dictionary implements an object and receives a key value pair, you can have a dynamic property name and whatever value you need (List of strings)

```
public class MyResponse
{
  public string Version { get; set; }
  public string StatusCode { get; set; }
  public string RequestId { get; set; }
  public bool Success { get; set; }
  public SomeResult Result { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, List<string>>  ValidationMessages {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Or even a `SortedList<string, string[]>`.

Comment: My comment has not been saved. Thank's a lot. it is working great.